# Is this voting pattern legit?

Tags: support, voting

I just noticed that an old answer of mine has had a LOT of recent upvotes.

See for yourself: [What made object oriented programming successful?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16196/4099)

Now, I happen to think it's a good answer - and I'm not objecting to the additional rep - but 26 upvotes in just one day **smells**. I'm just not active enough to hit the 200 rep limit on any given day.

So, could someone with sufficient rep (a moderator?) have a look to see what's going on? Love it to be legit, but (currently) inclined to believe it is not.

Comment: unless you (or someone who really likes you) has a ton of sock puppets, a good answer suddenly getting a lot of up votes isn't unheard of, and generally is caused from being linked on an external site or the question was put in the hot questions list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be an old answer, but the whole thread was bumped to the front page thrice today, as three new answers were posted. This new round of attention also lead to the question getting closed, the new answers are... not exactly what we're looking for (especially when there's already a thorough answer) and I suspect protecting the question from receiving further sub par answers did go through the close voters' minds.

I don't see anything suspicious there, but we (mods) don't really have access to more information than you do. If the votes were on several different posts of yours, we might had a case of someone going through your profile and serially upvoting you, but that's not what happened here, 26 (well, 27 *now*) different people upvoted your answer.

It's a genuinely good answer, and as far as I can see everything seems legit, enjoy the rep!

Comment: Thanks for looking into it - much appreciated. First time to hit the rep limit!

Comment: @Bevan - my voting to close on that question had nothing to do with your answer.  And I agree with Yannis & Maple Shaft that it's a solid answer.  The question, on the other hand, really isn't on-topic for P.SE anymore, and that's why I voted to close.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are seeing the normal ebb and flow of Programmers.  Typically when a question is searched for on Google, Programmers ends up somewhere on the first page if the question has been asked before here.  This person will sometimes bump the question with an answer, comment, vote, or an edit.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/179163/25476

The following answer was given about 11 hours ago from now so it looks like this user bumped it.  When this happens it makes its way to the home page for a while, which shows all recent activity on the site.  This will sometimes give it considerably more attention and then you see additional answers, comments, then finally 4 hours ago a 5th close vote.

So in other words it looks perfectly normal to me :)

Comment: Thanks too for looking into it - much appreciated.